# Find total sites hosted in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

How can I find the total number of sites hosted in an instance of IIS 7? It doesn't matter if it is in PowerShell, I just can't seem to find some trival way to find this information...

Answer (score 2):

Use appcmd.
Open cmd and execute:

- For 32 Bits

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > C:\temp\websites.txt

- For 64 Bits

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\appcmd list site > C:\temp\websites.txt

Your ouput file will have a full description of all sites in IIS 7.
Open the file with some text editor with line numbers, or use excel and take a look on total rows.

Answer (score 0):

The appcmd mentioned previously is pretty cool. But if you start Powershell and type:

```
get-website
```

You'll get a pretty listing of all the configured websites and bindings:

```
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Stopped    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
                                                                net.tcp 808:*
                                                                net.pipe *
                                                                net.msmq localhost
                                                                msmq.formatname localhost
```

You might need to add the IIS WebManagement snapin. But if you start Powershell from the `Administrative Tools` folder, it'll have the snapin already loaded.